# Locking table database access for unregistered ip address

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, locking, ip-address

Good Day Guys,

I am creating a system that will be up on my web server. the thing is when the users got their account details (username and password from the user table) then can open it anywhere outside the company. I dont know how to creeate this but i have some ways here:

1. Each computer has their respective ip address. What i want is the system will only work if accessed from within the company network and not from outside. Can you help me with this?
2. In addition for number one, how to lock tables when there is no user is logged-in and unlocking it when any user logs-in.

I am using mysql database, php, phpmyadmin... can you help please

Comment: Can you elaborate on point 2? What do you mean by lock the tables? If no-one is logged on, why would they be being used in the first place?

Comment: oh sorry....my mistake...number 2 is nothing....can you please help me on point 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
if($ip=="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx") //xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx will be your gateway ip
{
//your application code
}
```

Comment: how about the application code? what will i put on that location? and is it possible to register multi ip addresses? in this code?

Comment: application code is probably your index.php code and who has stopped you from using array??

Answer (score 0):

Actually the first one should be done in PHP, since your request to the DB will be sent only via the web server(hopefully)

```
                    print_r($_SERVER);
                    $myip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

If you however you have direct mysql access you restrict the logins revoke everything else
grant select on A_DATABASE_NAME.A_TABLE_NAME to 'login'@'hostname'

for 2, do you mean to actually don't allow anyone to access the data without the login right?
Just grant proper authorization. where you app is the only one that allows the login

i.e.
1. your db should only be accessible by 1 login account accessible via only from php server
2. Grant select on db.privatetable to tables that visible to outside net
3. Avoid Locking at all costs

Comment: Good day everyone, i just want to ask how to insert the real ip address to the mysql database: the flow here is that when the user will register his/her account details on the <form> (which consist of first name, last name, user name and password). now on the form there is a hidden input field that can call the ip address using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];. how could i insert in into the fifth column (ip) of the table users in the mysql database? anyhelp guys

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you  want to restrict access thats in th emysql database. If you want your own table create a new one. its not a good idea to play with default mysql tables